# Does Google Analytics account for browser mode or document mode in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-analytics, mode

Usage stats show that the number users with older versions of IE are thankfully decreasing but can this be relied on?

If a page is visited in IE9 but set to IE7 Browser mode and/or document mode, what does Google Analytics record this as? An IE9 visit or an IE7 visit?

Trying to get a handle on whether the stats recorded relate to the software installed or the visual experience so we can know whether the stats are safe to use as a basis for browser support for versions of IE.

Answer (score 1):

It's based on the browser mode/version, NOT the document mode.

I've tested it using the developer tools in IE and comparing that to reporting in Google Analytics. Here are two examples:

Example 1: Browser version IE6, document mode 5:
[image: Changing the IE browsing settings to mimic IE6 and doc mode 5]
[image: Google Analytics shows the browser type as IE6]

Example 2: Browser version IE8, document mode 10:
[image: Changing the IE browsing settings to mimic IE8 and doc mode 10]
[image: Google Analytics shows the browser type as IE8]

As far as I can tell, there is no way to determine the document type of the users browsing your website using Google Analytics.